# trying to parse a fetched xml file from one class to another

Tags: java, xml, parsing

im using android studio for a school project and im in the final stages now. the only thing i have left is for one class that has 2 spinners, one determining the program, and the other determining the semester, and a button that will then take those two spinners and spit out a URL pertaining to the schedule of that program and semester. The problem is, i dont know how to then take that spit out URL, and parse it into the other java class that displays a schedule. Below you will find the code attached, that works but doesnt display the correct schedule(since its hardcoded)

```
   StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
                sb.append("http://branko-cirovic.appspot.com/etcapp/timetables/timetable_"); sb.append(cid); sb.append(semester); sb.append(".xml");
                loc = sb.toString();

                Toast.makeText(ScheduleMainActivity.this,"You Selected : "
                        + loc, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                Intent toy7 = new Intent(ScheduleMainActivity.this, TimetableMainActivity.class);
                toy7.putExtra("Name", loc);
                startActivity(toy7);
```

That is the activity where im creating the intent and using the putExtra to use the data in the next activity

```
 public class GetXML extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    String src = null;
    String loc = (String) getIntent().getExtras().get("Name");

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(loc);
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            src = readStream(con.getInputStream());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return src;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        if (src == null)
            new AlertDialog.Builder(TimetableMainActivity.this).
                    setTitle("Error").setMessage("No Schedule Found").
                    setNeutralButton("Close", null).show();
        else {
            parseXML(src);
        }

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_timetable);

        days = new String[5][10];
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
                int k = i * 10 + j;
                days[i][j] = schedule.get(k);
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            list[i] = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();

        int count = hours.length;

        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                map.put("time", hours[i]);
                map.put("description", days[j][i]);
                list[j].add(map);
            }
        }

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        int today = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) - 2;

        pos = 0;
        if (today >= 0 && today <= 4)
            pos = today;

        ViewPager viewPager = findViewById(R.id.ViewPager);
        CustomPagerAdapter adapter = new CustomPagerAdapter(TimetableMainActivity.this, list);
        PagerTabStrip pagerTabStrip = findViewById(R.id.pager_tab);

        int color = Color.parseColor("#33b7ee");
        pagerTabStrip.setTabIndicatorColor(color);

        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(pos);
    }
```

This is where im getting an error. Im getting an IndexOut of bounds error and the app is crashing

```
2018-11-20 22:35:19.126 20681-20681/com.example.mr_ru.listview E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.mr_ru.listview, PID: 20681
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437)
    at com.example.mr_ru.listview.TimetableMainActivity$GetXML.onPostExecute(TimetableMainActivity.java:100)
    at com.example.mr_ru.listview.TimetableMainActivity$GetXML.onPostExecute(TimetableMainActivity.java:66)
    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:695)
    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:180)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:712)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

This is the error  btw

Comment: hi Shannon, you need to post the code as text in the question and not attached as image ;) is easier to assist you by simulating the question if needed

Comment: fixed it for you